# Python - Code does not run without #!/usr/bin/python

Tags: python, shell

Okay I am new to Python, but my code does not run if the line

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

is not present at the beginning of the file. Why is that ? What does it mean ? I thought it was used for to denote a python version if there were multiple versions installed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def main():
    a = [1,2,3]

    print a

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Omitting the #!/usr/bin/python gives the following error **only if** I execute it using

`./test.py` on Ubuntu

if however I use the python command to run then it runs fine without the `/usr/bin` line.

Comment: you may run your file like "python test.py" in any *nix environment. The first line actually tells the shell how to execute the rest of the script.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script

Answer (score 5):

The first line of the script beginning with `#!` is a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (sometimes called a hash-bang).

The following executable path denotes which interpreter should be used to process the following code (in your case, `/usr/bin/python`).

If you run the script from the shell with `python test.py`, you don't need a shebang - the executable is `python` and the script is passed to it as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

In Unix you can tell a file how it should be opened if it contains a script language (in your case Python).

This line is known as [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Answer (score 0):

`./filename` is used to run executable files, to execute it you need to specify the application required.
Whereas, in using `python filename.py` you already specify the application to use that is python in this case.